# Using wildcards with GQL -- Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

Is it possible to use a wildcard with GQL?  I would like to be able to pull all records that contain a particular word somewhere in their values.  I don't believe there is a "LIKE" filter.   Here is basically what I am trying to do:
Any advice you can give is greatly appreciated-

```
mentors_with_topic = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM MentorServices WHERE Services LIKE 'Reading'").get()
```

Comment: What are some examples of what you want your `like` to match against? You can't literally do a `like`, but if an index can be built on what you want to do, it will be possible.

Comment: Well, I would like for users to write a few sentence bio - and then have other users able to search by keywords that appears in their bio.

Comment: One idea I had is to convert the string (their bio) into a list ..and then possibly trying to match against each item in the list.  Would that be possible?

Comment: If you used a `StringListProperty`, I'd say it could work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you want to do, you're probably best served using the [`search` API](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/looking-for-search-find-it-on-google.html) (added in 1.7).

There are [docs available](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/), but essentially you create a new "search" index and "documents" which you must add to the index by creating them from your existing data. The search index is a different, fully searchable type of index which but which is still stored in your datastore.

---

As a hackish alternative to this, if you store the free text you want to search against in a `StringListProperty` (you will probably have to update your model and migrate your data to be split into individual words), then you can "search" against this with a simple equality operator (`=`) which is roughly equivalent to an `in` in python:

```
search_string = "Reading"
q = MentorServices.all()
q.filter("Services =", search_string)
q.fetch()
```

I strongly suggest using the `search` API instead of this, because:

- You have to migrate all of your `TextProperty` fields that you want to search to `StringListProperty` fields before this will work
- Using `StringListProperty` fields is not efficient for storing text
- The alternative `search` API was created precisely to avoid these kinds of solutions.

If you controlled how users entered the data, for example by having them enter a set of skills as tags, then they would be more easily saved as a `StringListProperty` and it would make more sense to search in this manner. For searching unstructured text, use the `search` API.

Comment: thanks jozzas, that helps a lot.  I will look into using the search API, and my fallback will be your idea of using tags-